# No Method Error in Lists#Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've done some research on Stack Overflow and tried a variety of solutions but nothing seems to be working.  I'm trying to render my ListsController show page, but I keep getting the error : undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass.  When I use the rails console, my params are passing the ID through, and I can call @list = List.find(params[:id] and then @list.name.  However, I keep getting the same error message.  My controller looks like this:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lists = List.order("created_at DESC")
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    if @list.save
      if request.xhr?
        # somehow only send back the html for the page update
        render :layout => false
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      @lists = List.all
      render :index
    end

    def show
      @list = List.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  private
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

My view currently looks like this:

```
<section class="todoapp">
  <header class="header">
    <h1><%= @list.name %></h1>
  </header>
  <section class="main">
    <input class="toggle-all" type="checkbox">
    <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
    <ul class="todo-list">
      <%= render @list.items %>
      <!-- exactly the same as: -->
      <%#= render :collection => @list.items, :partial => "items/item" %>
    </ul>
  </section>
</section>
```

I've tried using the line

## <%= @list.name if @list.name %>

but that doesn't seem to be ruling out the event of nil class either (even though params currently have an ID).

Comment: can you paste the `url` you are accessing when you get this error ?

Comment: list GET    /lists/:id(.:format)      lists#show

Comment: http://localhost:3000/lists/73

Comment: And you're sure `@list = List.find(73)` and then `puts @list.name if @list.name`  in a console is pulling the object and it isn't nil?

Comment: ok run `rails c` and find what this line returns `List.find(73)`

Comment: ok you have already tried it and it is working fine. can you paste the exact error with the stacktrace

Comment: 2.2.1 :001 > List.find(73)
  List Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 73]]
 => #<List id: 73, name: "yup! working!", created_at: "2015-08-29 16:12:20", updated_at: "2015-08-29 16:12:20"> 
2.2.1 :002 >

Comment: and here is the exact error:  Showing /Users/rebeccaades/Desktop/todo/app/views/lists/show.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"73"}

Comment: I didn't close out my def create and def show properly and it resulted in the nil class error.

Answer (score 0):

class ListsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @lists = List.order("created_at DESC")
    @list = List.new
  end

def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    if @list.save
      if request.xhr?
        # somehow only send back the html for the page update
        render :layout => false
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      @lists = List.all
      render :index
    end
  end

def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

private
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:name)
    end

end